# Member access not legal on system.decimal - LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am having a problem with my LINQ Query here. Every time it runs I get this error:

> Member access 'System.Decimal UnitPrice' of
>   'S00117372_FOOP202_CA2.Order_Detail' not legal on type
>   'S00117372_FOOP202_CA2.Order.

I cannot find out what the problem is with this but I think its something simple.

```
var t3 = from o in db.Orders
         join OrderID in db.Order_Details
         on o.OrderID equals OrderID.OrderID
         into g
         group o by new { o.CustomerID, g }
         into od
         select new 
         {
             od.Key,
             Column1 = (System.Decimal?)od.Key.g.Sum(p => p.UnitPrice * p.Quantity )
         };
Tab3.DataContext = t3;
```

This is the working version of the code in SQL:

```
use Northwind
go
select CustomerID, sum(UnitPrice * Quantity)
from dbo.[Order Details]
join Orders
on dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
group by dbo.Orders.CustomerID
```

Comment: What is the structure of `typeof(p)`?

Comment: Why are you casting it to a Nullable Decimal?

Comment: To be honest, I was only guessing what I have from googling linq joins groups and sums. I have only started LINQ recently so not too sure what I'm at. If anyone has a better way in which my code should be writted please let me know

Comment: A better route to get where you want to go might be to explain what you are trying to do, and what are you are trying to accomplish.  As with almost everything in life, context is important. :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson - if by `typeof(p)` you mean `p => p.UnitPrice * p.Quantity`, `p` will be the result (product) of UnitPrice and Quantity.

Comment: Yes, Tim you have it right there. Basically the entire code is meant to join the Orders table to the Order_Details table on the OrderID column. Then what I want my end result to be is to select the CustomerID and the value of (unitprice * quantity). Whats really getting to me is that I actually have this code working in SQL :P

Comment: I have my SQL code in the question now